# How can i find the Light component by tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class Flashlight : MonoBehaviour {

    Light flashlight;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        flashlight = GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if (flashlight.enabled)
            {
                flashlight.enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                flashlight.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since i have other Light components in the Hierarchy i added a tag to the flashlight object called it Flashlight.

But how can i get the correct Light by the Flashlight tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Start ()
{
    flashlight = FindGameObjectsWithTag("FlashLight").GetComponent<Light>();
}
```

Referenced from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)

Comment: I did: flashlight = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Flashlight"); but getting error: 
Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Light'

Comment: Check my answer again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public field or a getter, where you pick that exact reference